# Erro de plugin Maven Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Estou tentando executar um projeto no netbeans e está dando o seguinte erro "org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec". Pesquisei sobre o erro, e encontrei a seguinte solução: botão direito > propriedades > ações > alterar as ações que contém 1.2.1 para 1.6.0, porém, ao fazer isso o erro continua, agora na versão "org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec".

Log do erro:

```
        cd C:\Users\Jess\Desktop\Mainline-master\Mainline-        
master\MainlineOshi\MainlineOshi; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program 
Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_181" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 
8.2\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dexec.args=\"-classpath %classpath 
software.inicioLogin\" -Dexec.executable=\"C:\\Program 
Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_181\\bin\\java.exe\" - 
Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.2\\java\\maven- 
nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.codehaus.mojo:exec- 
maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec\""
Running NetBeans Compile On Save execution. Phase execution is skipped and 
output directories of dependency projects (with Compile on Save turned on) 
will be used instead of their jar artifacts.
Scanning for projects...

Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for 
com.mycompany:Mainline:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be 
unique: com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:jar -> version 7.0.0.jre10 vs 
6.4.0.jre8 @ line 37, column 21

It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the 
stability of your build.

For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such 
malformed projects.


------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building Mainline 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------
The POM for unknown.binary:AbsoluteLayout:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no 
dependency information available

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (default-cli) @ Mainline ---
Erro: Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal 
software.inicioLogin
Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:804)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:751)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:313)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

Mensagem de erro:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 7.841s
Finished at: Thu Nov 15 20:06:22 BRST 2018
Final Memory: 6M/123M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (default- 
cli) on project Mainline: Command execution failed. Process exited with an 
error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Arquivo POM:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"                 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>Mainline</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
        <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.oshi/oshi-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.oshi</groupId>
        <artifactId>oshi-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
        <artifactId>AbsoluteLayout</artifactId>
        <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0.jre10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.0.jre8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: atualize a pergunta com seu pom por favor

Comment: @LucasMiranda pergunta editada conforme solicitado.

Comment: tem uma tag repository escrito 'A temporary repository created by ...' deleta ela e tenta redar o build

Comment: @LucasMiranda apaguei a tag, executei novamente e deu o seguinte erro: "Failed to execute goal on project Mainline: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:Mainline:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact unknown.binary:AbsoluteLayout:jar:SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging."

Comment: troque essa dependencia pela <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.netbeans.external/AbsoluteLayout -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.netbeans.external</groupId>
    <artifactId>AbsoluteLayout</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE802</version>
</dependency>

Comment: @LucasMiranda notei que você mandou uma tag dependency e estávamos falando de uma tag repository. Ao trocar a repository por dependency deu erro, certeza que é pra colocar no mesmo lugar que a repository? Ou insiro essa tag dependency dentro das dependências já existentes no arquivo POM? Me desculpe as perguntas, sou iniciante na programação.

Comment: Boa tarde, Jessica, estava me referindo a substituição dessa dependencia aqui
 <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
        <artifactId>AbsoluteLayout</artifactId>
        <version>SNAPSHOT</version>